# Using IN operator at tablix filters issue

Tags: filter, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to add a filter with IN operator to my tablix. Problem is , my criteria values are already comma separated like A,B and C,D. Writing them like " 'A,B','C,D' doesn't seem to work.

I couldn't manage to get the filter working and all other questions/examples are for single word criteria. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue on my own  by using a =split("2B,2C",",") function and changing the split notation (the last ,) to something other than a comma. Works very fine.

I hope this would help and save time for other people in future.